# Is there a way to store previous html and if there are any changes in json then update only those changes in html?

Tags: javascript, json, dom, google-chrome-extension

I am working on a chrome extension for the very first time.
A brief info about the extension : It fetches json data from a url containing an array objects of Coding contests happening/to be happened on sites like Leetcode, Codeforces, etc and shows them in the html.So to make this happen, everytime the extension icon is clicked, the json data is fetched from the url and every single time html is cleared and new html is displayed (using js dom manipulation) by looping over the json which makes the page loading slow.
So how can i add/delete my html only with the new/removed json objects also maintaining the order of Contests on the basis of their time?

In short : Is there a way to store previous html and if there are any changes in json then update only those changes in html?
Using JS only

Comment: What you want is to keep track of JSON items\properties at pre-set time intervals (or at the user's discretion) to intercept insertions, cancellations or changes?

Comment: I want to update my html only when a change is occured in json fetched data, right now html is changing irrespective of the changes/no changes in json

Comment: "my html" stand for a page extension (html packed inside your extension) that you want it displays some info based on possible changement in a external fetched JSON file? i.g. JSON files changed and your extension page shows what is changed from last time?